# Set string variable content in princexml

Tags: css, django-templates, princexml

I'm using PrinceXML and Django Templates to generate a PDF. I'm able to set the content of a url but unable to set a string for the bottom left

```
@media print{
  @page { 
    @bottom-right {
      /* works */
      content: url({{ user.logo }})
    }
    @bottom-left {
      /* doesn't work */
      content: {{ user.uuid }};
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have to set the content differently for a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the template variable between double quotes like this :

```
content: "{{ user.uuid }}";
```

Django will only replace the template variable by its value. So if for example you have :

```
user.uuid = "My unique id"
```

Then

> content: {{ user.uuid }};

will become

> content: My unique id;

Which will not be interpreted as a string by PrinceXML